# JPA Eager loading related entities does not fix object references

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following tables on a postgresql database:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE phone
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  number character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  person_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_phone PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_phone_person FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I would like to have the following entities in java:

```
public class Person {
    ...
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Phone> phones;
    ...
    // constructors
    // getters and setters
}

public class Phone {
    ...
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    private Long personId;
    private Person person;
    ...
    // constructors
    // getters and setters
}
```

I created the entities through Eclipse based on the database, but, in Phone class it does not generate personId field which I would like to have, I have created this field/getters/setters and managed to get it to work to save person and its phones.

My problem here is that when I find a person through its id it brings the related phones, the related phones comes with its personId/person fields null. What I expect is JPA to bring my phones pointing to its parent person object instance.

Is that possible? Shouldn't this be the default behavior? Is it a configuration problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Posting the JPA mappings rather than the db tables would be more useful.